# Output from Github actions workflow goes to root but should go to docs folder

Tags: github-actions, github-pages

I'm trying to create a worker that builds storybook when changes are pushed to "main" branch . Output should be places inside "docs" folder. but for some reasion it always goes to root

```
name: Storybook
on:
  push:
    paths:
      - src/stories/**
      - src/components/**
jobs:
  build-and-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout ️
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          persist-credentials: false
      - name: Install and Build 
        run: |
          yarn
          yarn build-storybook
      - name: Deploy 
        uses: JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4
        with:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          BRANCH: main
          FOLDER: docs-build
          CLEAN: true
          TARGET_FOLDER: docs
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the names from caps seems to have done the trick ( also removed the GITHUB_TOKEN )

```
   with:
      branch: main
      folder: docs-build
      clean: true
      target-folder: docs
```

Comment: Well Yaml is case sensitive. And as a side note about the root directory, you can find it out by printing out ```${{ github.workspace }}``` (from a bash script or similar)